# react js onClick toggle class on different elements inside different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, onclick, router

i am fairly new to react and i am building an app that has 2 languages. you can switch between the languages from  the navbar using Redux to handle the state. i have a json file where i stored the text for both languages and used onClick to switch between them. it works great on every component and every page.
however my problem is on some components where i am using map() and find() functions to get data from a different json file so i feel like i am forced to find another solution to switch languagse on these components and the simplest solution i could think of is to hide/show a class between two h1 for example one for english and one for arabic.

how can i make an onClick function on the navbar button that will change the language and also show/hide a class on other components not a child component in order to show one of the two languages?

this is the Navbar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bubble as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import './Navbar.css';
import '../../../data/content.json'
const Provider = require('react-redux').Provider;
const createStore = require('redux').createStore;
const content = require('../../../reducer');

class Navbar extends Component {
  showSettings (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
        const data = this.props.data;
        let switchLanguage = this.props.switchLanguage;
    return (
      <div>
              <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down language">
                <li className="dropdown-button right"><a onClick={switchLanguage.bind(this,'en')} className="language-a">Eng</a></li>
                <li className="dropdown-button right"><a onClick={switchLanguage.bind(this,'ar')} className="language-a">عربي</a></li>
                <li className="right">
                  <p>CALL US: +905061162526</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
        <i onClick={ this.showSettings } className="material-icons sidenav-trigger right">menu</i>
        <Menu >
          <img className="sidenav-logo" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dd5e5iszi/image/upload/v1522222933/other/home-page-logo.png" alt="cayan group logo"/>
          <li className="link-wrapper">
            <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="menu-item" exact to="/">{data.home}</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="link-wrapper">
            <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="menu-item" exact to="/projects">{data.projects}</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="link-wrapper">
            <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="menu-item" exact to="/services">{data.services}</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="link-wrapper">
            <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="menu-item" exact to="/about">{data.about}</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="link-wrapper">
            <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="menu-item" exact to="/contact">{data.contact}</NavLink>
          </li>

        </Menu>
        <div className="navbar-fixed">
          <nav className="normal-nav">
            <div className="nav-wrapper">
              <a href="index.html" className="brand-logo"><img className="responsive-img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dd5e5iszi/image/upload/v1522221061/other/logo-nav.png" alt="cayan group logo"/></a>

              <ul className="nav-links center hide-on-med-and-down">

                <li className="link-wrapper">
                  <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="nav-link" exact to="/">{data.home}</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="link-wrapper">
                  <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="nav-link"  to="/projects">{data.projects}</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="link-wrapper">
                  <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="nav-link"  to="/services">{data.services}</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="link-wrapper">
                  <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="nav-link"  to="/about">{data.about}</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="link-wrapper">
                  <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="nav-link"  to="/contact">{data.contact}</NavLink>
                </li>

              </ul>


            </div>

          </nav>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Navbar;
```

this is the where i want to hide/show a class. on some

tags in want to show and hide one of them based on the language selected

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';

import PRODUCTS from '../../Data/CarouselData.js';

import './ProjectsCarousel.css';


class ProjectsCarousel extends Component {

  render() {
    const data = this.props.data;
              var settings = {
                dots: false,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 500,
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                autoplay: false,
                autoplaySpeed: 5000,
                responsive:[
                  { breakpoint: 400, settings: { slidesToShow: 1 } },
                  { breakpoint: 1024, settings: { slidesToShow: 2 } }
                ]
        };
    return (
      <div className="projetcsCarousel ">
              <div className="containermy">
                <div className="row">
                <div className="container">
                  <h1 className="body-h1">PROJECTS</h1>
                </div>

                <div className="carousel">
                  <div className="left-btn col s1">
                    <p>PREV</p>
                  </div>
                <Slider className="inner col s10" {...settings}>

                {PRODUCTS.map((product)=>{
                  return (
                  <a key={product.id} href={'/products/'+product.id}>

                    <div className='wrapper'>
                      <div className={'carouselImages cayan-'+product.id}>
                        <h6>{'CAYAN'+product.id}</h6>
                      </div>
                      <div className="description">
                        <h6>Description</h6>
                        <h5>{product.priceMin + ' - ' + product.priceMax}</h5>
                        <p>{product.description}</p>
                        <p>{product.descriptionAr}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className="project-info ">
                        <div className="col s6 project-info-icons left">
                          <i className="ion-ios-location-outline "></i>
                          <p>{product.location}</p>
                          <p>{product.locationAr}</p>
                          <br/>
                          <i className="ion-ios-home-outline"></i>
                          <p>{product.types}</p>
                          <br/>
                          <i className="ion-ios-photos-outline"></i>
                          <p>{product.area}</p>
                          <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col s6 project-info-icons right">
                          <i className="ion-ios-pricetag-outline "></i>
                          <p>{product.installment} months installments</p>
                          <br/>
                          <i className="ion-ios-gear-outline"></i>
                          <p>{product.status}</p>
                          <br/>
                          <i className="ion-ios-cart-outline"></i>
                          <p>{product.deliveryDate}</p>
                          <br/>
                        </div>
                        <button className="more-details">MORE DETAILS</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  )
                })}

                </Slider>
                <div className="right-btn col s1">
                  <p>NEXT</p>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}


export default ProjectsCarousel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from  after reading the question is you have to toggle between the elements on click by changing the class.
The solution I propose is change a single variable value onClick and use the variable to show and hide for example:

```
let isEnglish = true;
<h1 style={ display: isEnglish ? block : hidden }>{'Welcome'}</h1>
<h1 style={ display: isEnglish ? none : block }>{'Welcome in Arabic'}</h1>
```

Comment: thanks yes this is what i mean. but how can i access the isEnglish and set it to true or false based on what the user clicked on a different component.

i understand that i will declare isEnglish to true by default on the component that i want to change the style on but how can i change the value to false on click on different component

Comment: Why would you want to change the language when user clicks on a different component ? It's either the user reads English or not. it should be same for all the components .
Take some  button or other element which calls the function to manipulating the value of variable will depend on what you are using like redux, or just the react component states. For instance You can also take a global or window variable named isEnglish and do the task.

Answer (score 1):

This might resolve issue with multiple element class toggling.try this out:

https://jsfiddle.net/menomanabdulla/todu7m6g/11/

```js
class ToggoleApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    
    }
    
    this.toggleClass=this.toggleClass.bind(this);
    
  }
  
   toggleClass(e){
        let classes = 'my-class';
        let els = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class active');
        if(els){
            while (els[0]) {
                els[0].classList.remove('active')
            }
        }
        e.target.className = classes.replace('my-class','my-class active');
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Toggle Example</h2>
        <ul>
          <li className="my-class active" onClick={(e) =>this.toggleClass(e)}>
            One
          </li>
          <li className="my-class" onClick={(e) =>this.toggleClass(e)}>
            Two
          </li>
          <li className="my-class" onClick={(e) =>this.toggleClass(e)}>
            Three
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ToggoleApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.my-class{
  color: #FF3355;
}
.my-class.active{
  color: #33FF46;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```